# Oracle APEX automatic process execution

Tags: oracle-apex

I have made a process with a PL/SQL Function Body to calculate some numbers. The process is done only after double-clicking save changes. Which means I have to go into the report one more time and save the changes (which I didn't make) in order for the process to complete. Is there a way to execute processes automatically after first saving the data?

Comment: It's hard to tell what you have so far based on your current description. Double clicking just isn't a thing in the web world, for a start.

Comment: So what else do you need?

Comment: What are you double clicking? What happens during single click? Is this button submitting the page, or running a dynamic action? What changes aren't you making that you want to save - it doesn't really make sense? Does this help you at all? http://www.grassroots-oracle.com/2013/10/apex-101-dynamic-actions.html

Comment: Button is submitting the page. So, I have a report with 2 interactive grids (Master detail page) and when I enter the report and submit the changes, the process doesn't executes and I must enter the report again and click submit button again and then the process executes.

Comment: "Enter the report"? Perhaps you could build a sample on apex.oracle.com

Comment: The example is starting to help. Generally, when folks ask for an example on apex.oracle.com, they want developer credentials so the can see behind the scenes. Of course, you should only expose credentials to a demo workspace that doesn't contain any sensitive data. The next thing you need to provide are a series of steps that one of use could use to reproduce your issue. I read through your original question but I can't make much sense of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make new process with a PL/SQL Function Body, change Interactive Grid - Automatic Row Processing (DML)" to "PL/SQL Code and Editable Region to table_name.